# Generating an image from a raw vector containing a PNG image with Python.

Tags: python, r, python-imaging-library, cairo, rpy2

In R I create a raw vector containing a PNG image with the following test code.(format = ARGB (640 x 480))

```
library(Cairo)
library(png)

Cairo(type='raster')
x=seq(0,3,by=0.01)    
y=2*sin(2*pi*(x-1/4))
plot(x,y)  #Test plot
rawdata = writePNG(dev.capture(native=TRUE), raw())
assign("rawpng", rawdata, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

The resulting vector looks like this:`c(89, 50, 4e, 47, 0d, 0a, 1a, 0a, 00, 00, 00, 0d, 49, 48, 44, 
52, 00, 00, 02, 80, 00, 00, 01, e0, 08, 06, 00, 00, 00, 35, d1, 
dc, e4, 00, 00, 20, 00, 49, 44, 41, 54, 78, 9c, ec, dd, 77,
af, 5d, ee, cf, 75, 71, 
41, d6, 90, 99, e7, ec, b3, 66, 9f, b5, d7, 7a, d6, b3, c0, cc, 
cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, 
cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc, cc,..................................           b3, b0, fc, 1f, fe, 86, bd, ef, 71, 27, 9e, 88, 00, 00, 00, 00, 
49, 45, 4e, 44, ae, 42, 60, 82)`

Now i want to show the image in a Python canvas using the raw vector, but i can't seem to get it right. Using Rpy2 and Pil, I somehow managed to generate an image, but it's completly messed up.

```
rawdataVec = rpy2.robjects.globalenv['rawpng']
rawdataArray = numpy.asarray(rawdataVec)
newshape = (640,480,4)
newstrides = (rawdataArray.itemsize, rawdataArray.itemsize,rawdataArray.itemsize)
data = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(rawdataArray, shape=newshape, strides=newstrides)
img = Image.fromstring('RGBA', (640,480), data.tostring(),'raw','RGBA',0,1)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
```

I know that saving the plot as an image file and reloading it in Python would be much easier, but I need it without saving the file first.
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you write the image to a [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) buffer (which essentially writes an image to a "file" in memory) and then read it in from that buffer?

Comment: Thanks,  img = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(rawdataArray.tostring()))
worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently decoding using the `raw` decoder. Try `PNG` instead:

```
img = Image.fromstring('RGBA', (640, 480), data.tostring(), 'PNG')
```